# How multiply a line automatically, only changing name 1,2,3... continually

Tags: java, android

Hi I need to indentify multiple String LngLng with diferent names when i call data it from JSON, to multiply the response automatically, and this way to create diversy names like name1, name2, name3... that it this will change according to quantity of data from it get JSON

```
LatLng name1 = new LatLng (6.3490548, -75.5580200);

LatLng name2 = new LatLng (6.33, -75.56);... // to create this automatically, only changing name
```

My JSON Code

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("Response: ", response);

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    String getObject = jObj.getString("saagMRK");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);


                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                        LatLng name1 = new LatLng(parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT)), parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG)));// Multiply this line only changed the name1 to name2 to name3 automatically
...
```

Comment: Why does the variable name matter?  If you need to keep track of them after each iteration then add to a List or other type of Collection.

Comment: why geoQuery of geofire, when i add multiple marker, and try of remove a specific listener, it remove all listener, for the same name